# How to make bar count start at 1 for a given timeframe?

Tags: pine-script

Is there any way to make the barcount start at 1 for the first bar in the given time frame? as the picture show it now start from the first bar on chart...

````
study(title="candle count" ,overlay=true)

i_startTime = input(defval = timestamp("01 Jan 2022 08:30 +0000"), title = "Start Time", type = input.time)
i_endTime = input(defval = timestamp("01 Feb 2022 15:30 +0000"), title = "End Time", type = input.time)

inDateRange = time >= i_startTime and time <= i_endTime

Count = inDateRange ? bar_index : na

//Count = bar_index + 1

label.new(time >= i_startTime and time <= i_endTime ? bar_index : na,high,tostring(Count),textcolor=color.blue,style=label.style_none)```



[![`enter image description here`][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhCXH.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use your own variable declared with the var keyword so that is isn't reset every bar.

```
var int Count = 0

if inDateRange
    Count += 1
```